# Second Level UITableView not working in SWIFT

Tags: swift, uitableview

I've got a UITableView like so:

```swift
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class ChatViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var ConversationList: UITableView!
    let apiService = APIService()
    var conversations: [Conversation] = []
    var selectedConversation: Int?



    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ConversationList.separatorStyle = .none
        ConversationList.dataSource = self
        ConversationList.delegate = self

        // load Conversations
        self.apiService.getConversations(completion: {result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let conversations):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("NUMBER OF CONVERSATIONS: ", conversations.count)
                    self.conversations = conversations
                    self.ConversationList.reloadData()
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("An error occured \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        })
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.conversations.count
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ChatViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatViewCellController

        cell.UserName.text = self.conversations[indexPath[1]].participants![1].username
        let imgURL = URL(string: self.conversations[indexPath[1]].participants![1].profileimage!)
        cell.UserLogo.sd_setImage(with: imgURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "icon.turq.png"))
        return cell
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("selected row number ", indexPath)
        self.selectedConversation = indexPath[1]
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "ChatToChatDetail", sender: self)
    }



    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        let destination = segue.destination as! ChatDetailViewController
        destination.name = self.conversations[self.selectedConversation!].participants![1].username!
        destination.img = self.conversations[self.selectedConversation!].participants![1].profileimage!
    }


}
```

The UITableViewCell sits in a separate, simple class like so:

```swift
import UIKit

class ChatViewCellController: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var UserLogo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserName: UILabel!



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.UserLogo.clipsToBounds = true
        self.UserLogo.layer.cornerRadius = self.UserLogo.frame.size.width / 2
    }



    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

As shown above, selecting a specific cell (i.e conversation) in the UITableView loads another UIViewController via segue. That UIViewController then contains another UITableView:

```swift
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

class ChatDetailViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var UserLogo: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var UserName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var MessageList: UITableView!
    var name: String = ""
    var img: String = ""
    let apiService = APIService()
    var messages: [ChatMessage] = []


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // prepare header section:
        self.MessageList.separatorStyle = .none
        let imgURL = URL(string: self.img)
        self.UserLogo.sd_setImage(with: imgURL, placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "icon.turq.png"))
        self.UserLogo.clipsToBounds = true
        self.UserLogo.layer.cornerRadius = self.UserLogo.frame.size.width / 2
        self.UserName.text = self.name

        // TODO: load messages

        self.MessageList.reloadData()
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MessageViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageViewCellController
        cell.ChatMessageText.text = "foo"

        return cell
    }
}
```

The UITableViewCell for the above UITableView is again sitting in a separate, simple class:

```swift
import UIKit

class ChatMessageViewCellController: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var ChatMessageBubble: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ChatMessageText: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        print("I'm awake")
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Everything works fine up until a certain point. The first Table View loads and shows all Chats. Clicking on a Chat loads the new View with the header section, showing the Logo and Name of the Chat partner at the top of the screen and a Table underneath it. However, that table does not contain anything. To my understanding, with this code, it should show 10 rows saying "foo" and print 10 times "I'm awake" to the console.

What am I missing or doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second ViewController, you are not setting `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource`. What you need to add to `viewDidLoad`:

```
MessageList.delegate = self
MessageList.dataSource = self
```

Bonus, for future change `self.selectedConversation = indexPath[1]` in first view controller to prevent bug - it will always take second model, even if you have only one.

Also, try to avoid upper case for attributes, e.g. MessageList -> messageList.